# How can I add only particular key value pairs from one object to another?

Tags: javascript

suppose,

```
obj1 = 
0: {
description: "",
holiday: false,
id: "",
isWeekend: false,
percent: 0,
pmDescription: "",
pmHours: 0,
productivity: 0,
projectName: "rgffgfg",
sowId: "7396",
time: 1591641000000,
userHours: 0,
userName: "hemant tripathi",
wfh: false,
},
1: {
description: "",
holiday: false,
id: "",
isWeekend: false,
percent: 0,
pmDescription: "",
pmHours: 0,
productivity: 0,
projectName: "rgffgfg",
sowId: "7396",
time: 1591641000000,
userHours: 0,
userName: "hemant tripathi",
wfh: false,
}
2: {
description: "",
holiday: false,
id: "",
isWeekend: false,
percent: 0,
pmDescription: "",
pmHours: 0,
productivity: 0,
projectName: "rgffgfg",
sowId: "7396",
time: 1591641000000,
userHours: 0,
userName: "hemant tripathi",
wfh: false,
}


obj2: {}
```

I just want to add 3 key-value pairs in obj2.
I want to loop through and access obj1. And add only 3 key-value pairs in obj2 ('description' , 'userHours' , 'userName') .I want to add these 3 key-value pairs.  How can we do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let obj1= [{
description: "",
holiday: false,
id: "",
isWeekend: false,
percent: 0,userHours: 0,userName: 'Ab'
},
{
description: "",
holiday: false,
id: "",
isWeekend: false,
percent: 0,userHours: 0,userName: 'Abcd'
}];

let obj2 = obj1.map(data => ({description: data.description, userHours: data.userHours, userName: data.userName}));
```

Comment: How can we do it when we have to loop through multiple objects?  Have edited the question

Comment: @UmangMehra I have updated the code which will support for array of objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can just assign the values as such.

```js
let obj1 = [{
  description: "",
  holiday: false,
  id: "",
  isWeekend: false,
  percent: 0,
  pmDescription: "",
  pmHours: 0,
  productivity: 0,
  projectName: "rgffgfg",
  sowId: "7396",
  time: 1591641000000,
  userHours: 0,
  userName: "hemant tripathi",
  wfh: false,
}, {
  description: "",
  holiday: false,
  id: "",
  isWeekend: false,
  percent: 0,
  pmDescription: "",
  pmHours: 0,
  productivity: 0,
  projectName: "rgffgfg",
  sowId: "7396",
  time: 1591641000000,
  userHours: 0,
  userName: "hemant tripathi",
  wfh: false,
}, {
  description: "",
  holiday: false,
  id: "",
  isWeekend: false,
  percent: 0,
  pmDescription: "",
  pmHours: 0,
  productivity: 0,
  projectName: "rgffgfg",
  sowId: "7396",
  time: 1591641000000,
  userHours: 0,
  userName: "hemant tripathi",
  wfh: false,
}]

let obj2 = []
obj1.forEach(o => {
  obj2.push({
    description: o.description,
    userHours: o.userHours,
    userName: o.userName
  })
})
console.log(obj2)
```

Comment: How about now when we have to loop through multiple objects?

Comment: Yes array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your need is to allow certain keys from object, so u create a list with whatever keys you need to map in the list acceptedKey.

var acceptedKey=["Id","description","holiday"]
for(var key in obj1)
{
if(acceptedKey.includes(key))
{
var newDict=[];
newDict.push(key:key,
value:obj1[key])
}
}

Comment: Generally just pasting code without explanation is discouraged on SO. Please edit your answer to explain your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate `obj1` and map with new array `obj2` with required keys.

```
const obj2 = obj1.map((val) => ({
  'userName': val.userName,
  'userHours': val.userHours,
  'description': val.description,
}))

console.log(obj2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will copy your array of objects into another array of objects including only the keys you want.

```
const source1 = {
  key1: "value1_s1",
  key2: "value2_s1",
  key3: "value3_s1"
  // ...
}

const source2 = {
  key1: "value1_s2",
  key2: "value2_s2",
  key3: "value3_s2"
  // ...
}

const objArr = [source1, source2]; // ...

const keysToCopy = ["key1", "key2"]; // ...

const destObjArr = objArr.map(o => Object.assign({}, Object.keys(o).reduce((obj, k) => {
    if(keysToCopy.includes(k)) obj[k] = o[k];
  return obj;
}, {}) ));

console.log(destObjArr);

/* Outputs 
[{
  key1: "value1_s1",
  key2: "value2_s1"
}, {
  key1: "value1_s2",
  key2: "value2_s2"
}]

*/
```